# Chart js - how do I have the color as green on upward trends and red on downward trends?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chart.js

I have a chart js graph for crypto prices and I'm not sure how to have the line turn green when it goes up and red when it goes down.

I tried looking in the docs but there isn't much about it, and I didn't really find anything else online.

Is there a way to color the specific line segments? maybe that could help

Here's my chart js graph

```
const renderGraph = () => {
    let dates = [];
    let prices = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < coinData.length; i++) {
      dates.push(i);
      prices.push(coinData[i][1]);
    }

    const ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart");

    const data = {
      labels: dates,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Price",
          data: prices,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: "rgb(153, 153, 153)",
        },
      ],
    };
    const options = {
      animation: {
        duration: 0,
      },
      hover: {
        animationDuration: 0,
      },
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 2,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false,
            },
          },
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    new Chart(ctx1, {
      type: "line",
      data: data,
      options: options,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Its described here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html